# would be/ was/ were - differences

Tags: verbs, adjectives, modal-verbs

1.Around midnight, as we left the previous year behind and moved into the new year, my mom **would be** busy cooking for the guests. I didn't like crowds so I stayed in the living room watching the telly.

2.Around midnight, as we left the previous year behind and moved into the new year, my mom **was** busy cooking for the guests. I didn't like crowds so I stayed in the living room watching the telly.

3.Around midnight, as we left the previous year behind and moved into the new year, my mom **cooked** for the guests. I didn't like crowds so I stayed in the living room watching the telly.

Let's say the speaker was asked how they spent the new year's and they answered with one of the responses mentioned above.

How do the responses differ in meaning from one another?

Comment: You say *the speaker was asked how they spent the New Year* (note - not ***year's***), but that itself is ambiguous as to whether they're being asked about ***one specific New Year***, or the "generic" case (what do they ***usually*** do at New Year?). Your first *(**would be busy cooking**)* example would only work for the second of those two scenarios. Whether to use Past Continuous (#2) or Simple Past (#3) is effectively a stylistic choice here, depending on whether you want to talk about *what happened in the past*, or *what **was happening, at some specific moment** in the past*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Past Vs Past Continuous](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/150835/simple-past-vs-past-continuous) Also [Past Continuous vs Past Simple](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/154478/past-continuous-vs-past-simple) and probably many more.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for the answer. 
If you want, now that i've got an answer, I can remove the question.
Should I?

Comment: No! Don't remove it! There probably are several other previous questions on the same subject, but the more different ones we have, the more likely it is that ***future*** visitors will be able to find one of them. That's because every different question will use different words, so there's more chance that one of them will match whatever the new querent types in for a search. And even if they don't bother checking before asking, the system itself can suggest "Earlier questions that seem to match what you're asking", so they'll get a nudge before clicking on "Post your Question".

Comment: Note that although I voted to *close* your question (because I think it's a duplicate), that doesn't cost you anything in terms of "reputation" here. And I see no justification for anyone *downvoting* your question (which *would* lead to loss of rep points). Anyway, I've just given you an upvote purely because you've taken the trouble to ask about site etiquette, even though the moderators here would probably say that's not a valid reason to upvote! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're very generous. I'm keeping the question, I guess. :)